# Probability problem with combinations

Tags: probability

There are $10$ floors in the building and $5$ people get into the elevator and each person can get out in any floor, what's the probability that two people will get off in one floor and the others get out one at a time? It doesn't mention where the lift stops.

I've been dragging my head around this for a few hours and can't figure it out. If it helps, the answer is $\frac{504}{1000}$ I just want to figure out how do you get to this answer.

Comment: Using some unstated assumptions, I get the answer $504/1287$. I don't see how the denominator of the answer could be $1000$.

Comment: I got a different answer:$$\frac{\binom{10}{4} * 4}{\binom{5 + 10 - 1}{5}} = \frac{60}{143}$$

Comment: I assume they get off on a different floor than where they started, so there are 9 floors at which they could get off. There are 9 choices of floor where two people leave, and 8-choose-3 possible floor choices where the other people get off individually. $9\binom{8}{3}=9\cdot\frac{8!}{3!5!}=504$. This assumes all of those possibilities are equally likely.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis this makes a lot of sence, I did not think about the fact that there can be only 9 floors people can get off, but how would the total posibility calculation look like? I mean how do you get the 1000 total posibilities?

Comment: As I said, I get $1287$. This is the number of ways you can distribute 5 indistinguishable things into 9  numbered boxes. Using the "stars and bars" method this is equal to $\binom{9+5-1}{9-1}=\binom{13}{8}=1287$.